# Spatially combining the latitude and longitude of two data frames by group

Tags: r

We have two data frames (ddd, env0). We want to join them spatially based on their proximity in latitude and longitude, and we want to choose the nearest one from the same "storm".

```
head(ddd)
storm lat long Mesh3rd
1 270 34.88750 137.2562 52372260
2 270 34.88750 137.2688 52372261
3 270 34.89583 137.2562 52372270
4 40 24.89581 144.2688 52372271
5 40 24.89593 144.2812 52372272
6 40 24.89683 144.2937 52372273

head(env0)
storm time track_time lat long track_env track_pres track_wind
1 270 1 55286.00 34.99216 137.5000 1010.416 1008.19 13.22159
2 270 2 55286.25 34.99216 140.6250 1008.091 1005.41 14.09173
3 270 3 55286.50 34.43054 142.3125 1008.779 1006.15 15.27882
4 40 4 55286.75 24.99216 144.0000 1006.264 1003.04 14.82848
5 40 5 55287.00 24.99216 145.5625 1007.882 1004.36 14.56058
6 40 6 55287.25 24.43054 146.6875 1005.603 1002.48 15.59767
```

The code we tried is as follows

```
temp <- ddd
temp3 <- split(ddd, f = dd$storm)
coordinates(temp) <- ~long+lat
mylist <- split(temp, f = temp$storm)

names(env0)<-c("storm","time","track_time","lat","long","track_env",
"track_pres","track_wind")
u<-unique(temp$storm)
envv<-filter(env0, storm %in% u)

temp1 <- envv
temp4 <- split(envv, f = envv$storm)
coordinates(temp1) <- ~long+lat
mylist1 <- split(temp1, f = temp1$storm)

test<-mylist
for(i in 1:length(mylist)){
test[[i]]<-pointDistance(mylist[[i]],mylist1[[i]],lonlat = TRUE, allpairs = TRUE)
}

nearest1<-temp3[[1]]
for(i in 1:length(test)){
nearest1[[i]] <- apply(test[[i]], 1, which.min)
}

sptsd<-mylist[[1]]
for(i in 1:length(mylist)){
sptsd[[i]]<- cbind(temp3[[i]], temp4[[i]][nearest1[[i]],1:8])
}
```

Then here is the result we want.

```
storm lat long Mesh3rd time track_time lat long track_env track_pres track_wind
1 270 34.88750 137.2562 52372260 1 55286 34.99216 137.5000 1010.416 1008.19 13.22159
2 270 34.88750 137.2688 52372261 1 55286 34.99216 137.5000 1010.416 1008.19 13.22159
3 270 34.89583 137.2562 52372270 1 55286 34.99216 137.5000 1010.416 1008.19 13.22159
4 40 24.89581 144.2688 52372271 4 55286.75 24.99216 144.0000 1006.264 1003.04 14.82848
5 40 24.89593 146.2812 52372272 4 55286.75 24.99216 144.0000 1006.264 1003.04 14.82848
6 40 24.89683 146.2937 52372273 4 55286.75 24.99216 144.0000 1006.264 1003.04 14.82848
```

---

And, the example was not adequate for my question (thank you very much for the notice!), then I revised the example data.

```
>head(ddd)
storm lat long Mesh3rd
1 270 34.8 137.2 52372260
2 270 35.0 137.2 52372261
3 270 35.2 137.2 52372270
4 40 34.8 137.2 52372260
5 40 35.0 137.2 52372261
6 40 35.2 137.2 52372270

>head(env0)
head(env0)
storm time track_time lat long track_env track_pres track_wind
1 270 1 55286.00 34.8 137.5 1010.416 1008.19 13.22159
2 270 2 55286.25 35.8 137.5 1008.091 1005.41 14.09173
3 270 3 55286.50 36.8 137.5 1008.779 1006.15 15.27882
4 40 4 55286.75 34.9 137.5 1006.264 1003.04 14.82848
5 40 5 55287.00 34.1 137.5 1007.882 1004.36 14.56058
6 40 6 55287.25 34.2 137.5 1005.603 1002.48 15.59767

#the result I want

storm lat long Mesh3rd time track_time lat long track_env track_pres track_wind
1 270 34.8 137.2 52372260 1 55286.00 34.8 137.5 1010.416 1008.19 13.22159
2 270 35.0 137.2 52372261 1 55286.00 34.8 137.5 1010.416 1008.19 13.22159
3 270 35.2 137.2 52372270 2 55286.25 35.8 137.5 1008.091 1005.41 14.09173
4 40 34.8 137.2 52372260 4 55286.75 34.9 137.5 1006.264 1003.04 14.82848
5 40 35.0 137.2 52372261 4 55286.75 34.9 137.5 1006.264 1003.04 14.82848
6 40 35.2 137.2 52372270 4 55286.75 34.9 137.5 1006.264 1003.04 14.82848
```

I am grateful for your help.

Comment: Hi maria, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add a part of your data that we can join, together with the expected output? Your two data examples have different values of `storm`, and as I understand, you want to join the same ones together. Also, how large is your data? If it is small, you could simply join by `storm` and afterwards filter the closest one. If it is large, this becomes unfeasible.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out. I added the result we want and changed the example of the data. Actually, there are huge amount of data we have.

Answer (score 0):

A spatial join using `st_nearest_feature` should work.

The code below works on your example data, but some grouping may be needed depending on the full datasets.

```r
ddd <- tibble::tribble(
  ~storm,     ~lat,    ~long,  ~Mesh3rd,
    270L,  34.8875, 137.2562, 52372260L,
    270L,  34.8875, 137.2688, 52372261L,
    270L, 34.89583, 137.2562, 52372270L,
     40L, 24.89581, 144.2688, 52372271L,
     40L, 24.89593, 144.2812, 52372272L,
     40L, 24.89683, 144.2937, 52372273L
  )


env0 <- tibble::tribble(
          ~storm, ~time, ~track_time,     ~lat,    ~long, ~track_env, ~track_pres, ~track_wind,
            270L,    1L,       55286, 34.99216,    137.5,   1010.416,     1008.19,    13.22159,
            270L,    2L,    55286.25, 34.99216,  140.625,   1008.091,     1005.41,    14.09173,
            270L,    3L,     55286.5, 34.43054, 142.3125,   1008.779,     1006.15,    15.27882,
             40L,    4L,    55286.75, 24.99216,      144,   1006.264,     1003.04,    14.82848,
             40L,    5L,       55287, 24.99216, 145.5625,   1007.882,     1004.36,    14.56058,
             40L,    6L,    55287.25, 24.43054, 146.6875,   1005.603,     1002.48,    15.59767
          )

library(sf) 
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.1, GDAL 3.1.3, PROJ 7.1.1

ddd_sf <- st_as_sf(ddd, coords = c('lat', 'long'))
env0_sf <- st_as_sf(env0, coords = c('lat', 'long'))

st_join(ddd_sf, env0_sf, join = st_nearest_feature)
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 8 fields
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 24.89581 ymin: 137.2562 xmax: 34.89583 ymax: 144.2937
#> CRS:            NA
#> # A tibble: 6 x 9
#>   storm.x Mesh3rd                  geometry storm.y  time track_time track_env
#> *   <int>   <int>                   <POINT>   <int> <int>      <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     270  5.24e7        (34.8875 137.2562)     270     1     55286      1010.
#> 2     270  5.24e7        (34.8875 137.2688)     270     1     55286      1010.
#> 3     270  5.24e7       (34.89583 137.2562)     270     1     55286      1010.
#> 4      40  5.24e7       (24.89581 144.2688)      40     4     55287.     1006.
#> 5      40  5.24e7       (24.89593 144.2812)      40     4     55287.     1006.
#> 6      40  5.24e7       (24.89683 144.2937)      40     4     55287.     1006.
#> # … with 2 more variables: track_pres <dbl>, track_wind <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

#### *edit:*

Your updated data doesn't make the example much clearer, but here's an alternative.  Taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62866685/7547327

```
library(purrr)

# split the objects based on the storm column
ddd_sf_split <- split(ddd_sf, ddd_sf$storm)
env0_sf_split <- split(env0_sf, env0_sf$storm)

# use purrr to join them
map2_dfr(ddd_sf_split, env0_sf_split, ~ .x %>% st_join(.y, st_nearest_feature))

Simple feature collection with 6 features and 8 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 137.2 ymin: 34.8 xmax: 137.2 ymax: 35.2
CRS:            NA
# A tibble: 6 x 9
  storm.x  Mesh3rd     geometry storm.y  time track_time track_env track_pres track_wind
*   <int>    <int>      <POINT>   <int> <int>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1      40 52372260 (137.2 34.8)      40     4     55287.     1006.      1003.       14.8
2      40 52372261   (137.2 35)      40     4     55287.     1006.      1003.       14.8
3      40 52372270 (137.2 35.2)      40     4     55287.     1006.      1003.       14.8
4     270 52372260 (137.2 34.8)     270     1     55286      1010.      1008.       13.2
5     270 52372261   (137.2 35)     270     1     55286      1010.      1008.       13.2
6     270 52372270 (137.2 35.2)     270     1     55286      1010.      1008.       13.2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. Your explanations have helped me to better understand the problem I am facing. If you have time, could you please take a look at the updated data example?

Comment: @maria I've updated the answer, but I think the sample data is still ambiguous.

Comment: @ mrhellmann Thank you very much for great support. I got an error "Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths: * `.x` has length 233 * `.y` has length 400" from the last code. I think this is due to the fact that the example data contains some ambiguities, although you pointed this out. I may get this error because the number of points is not necessarily equal between the two data sets.

Comment: @maria you're probably getting the error because the two objects have a different number of unique storms. Filter the datasets so that every unique value for the storm column is in both sets of data.

Comment: I could run the code you taught me by making the number of storms same in the two data sets. Thank you very much again.

Comment: @maria I'm glad it worked out for you.  You may want to consider accepting the answer, and welcome to stackoverflow.